# How to download a mySQL table from a remote server from terminal

Tags: mysql, ssh, terminal

I'm ssh-ed into a remote MySQL server through my Mac OS terminal. I'm in a database and looking at a table I want to download to my desktop. How do I download it? I've heard of mysqldump, but it confuses me. I'm very new to mySQL and databases in general and can't risk messing up this database somehow. Can someone give me the exact command to download a table? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're logged in using ssh that means you have access to a shell. find the location of the database file and then use scp to download it.

the command would look something like this:

```
scp -P 1234 user1@mysql.server.com:/location/of/source/file /location/of/destination

-P 1234: port number 1234 (may vary in your case)
user1: username
mysql.server.com: domain
/location/of/source/file: location of the database file on the server
/location/of/destination: location where you want to save the file on your computer
```

you also want to make sure you have necessary rights to copy the file using scp.

after you download it you can use a database browser to check out the contents.